# xstring : \IfStrEq and macro as string

Tags: xstring

I don't understand how \IfStrEq from xstring works.

Why this code doesn't show "This is text" ?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}
    
\DeclareDocumentCommand \field {} {text}
    
\begin{document}
  \IfStrEq{\field}{text}{This is text}{Why this is not text?}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But the manual says "The command \fullexpandarg is called by default, so all the arguments are fully expanded"

Comment: But \field is defined with \DeclareDocumentCommand and so is very non-expandable.  Try with `\newcommand\field{text}`.

Comment: without xparse you are seeing the effect of `\protected\def\field{text}`  and `text`

Comment: ok, this is because \field is protected (normal behavior of \DeclareDocumentCommand)
using \def solves the problem.
Thank you very much David and Ulrike

Comment: `\field` is *not* a string, but something eventually printing `text`. Using `\IfStrEq` is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `\field` is protected (normal behavior of `\DeclareDocumentCommand`). Using `\def` solves the problem.